How to wait multiple dynamic number of awaitable functions parallely
I am using Boost 1.84.0.
Boost Asio has some of multiple parallel co_wait functionality.
I realized that the number of waiting elements are sometimes static but sometimes dynamically decided.

Static number  example, async_read and timeout (2).
Dynamic number example, async_write all connected chat clients and all of them are finished then returns output a message something like "message is delivered."

Waiting static(fixed) number of async functions
It seems that taking variadic Ops parameter version requires that the number of async operation should be decided at the compilation time. This can be used static number of multiple waitihg that are using deferred and/or experimental::use_promise. It cannot be used with use_awaitable and/or user defined awaitable<T> func().
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/experimental__make_parallel_group/overload2.html
experimental::awaitable_operator can be used static number of multiple waiting that are using use_awaitable and/or user defined awaitable<T> func(). It cannot be used with deferredand/orexperimental::use_promise`.
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/composition/cpp20_coroutines.html#boost_asio.overview.composition.cpp20_coroutines.co_ordinating_parallel_coroutines
Waiting dynamic number of async functions
For dynamic number of async functions, we can use range version of experimental::make_parallel_group.
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/experimental__make_parallel_group/overload2.html
Here is a code example:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/experimental/co_composed.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/experimental/promise.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/experimental/use_promise.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/experimental/parallel_group.hpp>
namespace as = boost::asio;

as::awaitable<void> test() {
    auto exe = co_await as::this_coro::executor;
    using op_type = decltype(as::post(exe, as::append(as::deferred, int{})));
    std::vector<op_type> ops;
    for (int i = 0; i != 5; ++i) {
        ops.push_back(as::post(exe, as::append(as::deferred, i*10)));
    }
    auto [orders, values] = 
        co_await as::experimental::make_parallel_group(
            ops
        ).async_wait(
            as::experimental::wait_for_all(),
            as::deferred
        );
    for (auto order : orders) {
        std::cout << order << " " << values[order] << std::endl;
    }
    co_return;
}

int main() {
    as::io_context ioc;
    as::co_spawn(
        ioc.get_executor(),
        test,
        [](auto...){ std::cout << "async_func() finished" << std::endl; }
    );
    ioc.run();
    std::cout << "main() finished" << std::endl;
}

godbolt link: https://godbolt.org/z/c6ao6883c
This can be used dynamic number of multiple waitihg that are using deferred and/or experimental::use_promise. However, it cannot be used with use_awaitable and/or user defined awaitable<T> func().
My current solution
I give up to use awaitable functions in this situation. Instead of that, I use CompletionToken stype async functions.
Once I use awaitable<T> func(), that function cannot be waited dynamically. So if I need dynamic waiting, I keep my async_functions as the following style:
template <typename CompletionToken>
auto completion_token_based_async_func(as::any_io_executor exe, CompletionToken&& token) {
    return as::async_initiate<
        CompletionToken,
        void()
    >(
        as::experimental::co_composed<
            void()
        >(
            [](
                auto /* state */,
                as::any_io_executor exe
            ) -> void {
                // co_await awaitable_function() // error
                co_await other_async_func(as::deferred);
                co_return {};
            }
        ),
        token
    );
}

In the co_composed lambda expression, I cannot call the function that has awaitable return type. So I need to apply the same style for the callee functions.
That works well for me. However, I may be overlooking something more elegant way.
Is there any better way to wait parallely dynamic number of async functions ?
